# Regarding IoT EDGE server setup on desktop

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge

I am pretty new regarding IoT EDGE server setups, I am looking for suggestions or any tutorials that can guide me to set up IoT-EDGE servers on my desktop

Comment: Just checking back, let me know if you need further assistance, please mark helpful responses as answer, which may be helpful to other community members.

Answer (score 2):

Azure IoT Edge extends IoT Hub. Analyze device data locally instead of in the cloud to send less data to the cloud, react to events quickly, and operate offline.

For more information on complete Azure IoT Edge  quickstart tutorials, please visit the below mentioned Microsoft's portal.

[Azure IoT Edge documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/)

Microsoft's learning paths which gives a step by step learning.

[Introduction to Azure IoT Edge.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/introduction-iot-edge/)

The below article lists the steps to install the Azure IoT Edge runtime on your Windows x64 (AMD/Intel) system using Windows containers.

[Install the Azure IoT Edge runtime on Windows.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge-windows)

The below article lists the steps to install the Azure IoT Edge runtime on an X64, ARM32, or ARM64 Linux device.

[Install the Azure IoT Edge runtime on Debian-based Linux systems.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge-linux)

If you are stuck or have any questions on your learning journey please follow below link to get connected with wonderful community groups and forums.

[Azure IoT support and help options.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-fundamentals/iot-support-help)